# Passing parameters through the url

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am able to access a report, that I created with ireport. I am using an url which let's me have a look at my report from the JasperServer interface. It looks like following:

```
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&standAlone=true&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Freports%2Fsamples%2FTest&reportUnit=%2Freports%2Fsamples%2FTest%2FEinReport&j_acegi_security_check&j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=jasperadmin
```

My question is: can one ***pass parameters*** through this url and when it is possible, how is it done? I have 3 variables in my SQL query in iReport called, Startdatum, Enddatum and username.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had to add [input controls](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-user-guide/adding-input-controls) in the JasperServer interface and then add those parameters.

**before**

```
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&standAlone=true&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Freports%2Fsamples%2FTest&reportUnit=%2Freports%2Fsamples%2FTest%2FEinReport&j_acegi_security_check&j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=jasperadmin
```

**after**

```
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&standAlone=true&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Freports%2Fsamples%2FTest&reportUnit=%2Freports%2Fsamples%2FTest%2FEinReport&j_acegi_security_check&j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=jasperadmin&Startdatum=2014-04-08&Enddatum=2014-04-11&username=firstUser
```

Basically just adding *input controls* and these parameters to the url.

```
&Startdatum=2014-04-08&Enddatum=2014-04-11&username=firstUser
```

Comment: But this would only be valid for a specific locale, right? For instance, if you use "de_CH", this dates could not be transformed into dates by the JasperReports engine. Am I right?

Comment: I tried this but adding input controls takes me to input control screen filed with values passed in url. Is there a way i can directly navigate to report result screen(bypassing the input controls screen)